# Dropdown Autoclose on clicking another dropdown in Bootstrap Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a vertical navigation menu,and in it there are various dropdowns.
These dropdowns are build using ul-li.The 'li' slide down when clicked on the ul.
There are 5 dropdowns for eg 'A','B','C','D','E'.Now if i click on 'A' it should slide down which it does,now if i click on 'B',it should slide down and the 'A' should autoclose.In my case,B is opening but the 'A' still remains open.I want it to close when 'B' opens.`
        
            
                
                         
                            Toggle navigation

```
      <div> 

        <ul class="list-unstyled main-menu">
     <li class="dropdown" >
                <label class="navbar-collapse-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#jay">
                  Jay<b class="caret"></b>
                </label>    
                <div class="collapse" id="jay">
                        <a href="#/emailConfig" class="list-group-item"     >Email Configuration </a>
                        <a href="#/showEmailConfig" class="list-group-item" >Show Email Configuration</a>
                        <a href="#/languageSetting" class="list-group-item" >Language Setting</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown" >
                <label class="navbar-collapse-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#pooja">

                  Pooja<b class="caret"></b>
                </label>
                </a>
                <div class="collapse" id="pooja">
                        <a href="#/initSetting" class="list-group-item" style="background-color:#222;border:none">Init Settings </a>
                        <a href="#/dateSettings" class="list-group-item" style="background-color:#222;border:none">Date and Time Settings</a>
                        <a href="#/configSettings" class="list-group-item" style="background-color:#222;border:none">Config Settings</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <label class="navbar-collapse-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#raju">
                  Raju<b class="caret"></b>
                </label>
                <div class="collapse" id="raju">
                        <a href="#/home" class="list-group-item" style="background-color:#222;border:none">Add User </a>
                        <a href="#/graph" class="list-group-item" style="background-color:#222;border:none">Graph</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <label class="navbar-collapse-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mohit">
                  Mohit<b class="caret"></b>
                </label>
                    <div class="collapse" id="mohit">
                        <a href="#login/" class="list-group-item" style="background-color:#222;border:none">Login </a>
                        <a href="#/AddUserInfo" class="list-group-item" style="background-color:#222;border:none">Add User Info</a>
                        <a href="#/showUserInfo" class="list-group-item" style="background-color:#222;border:none">Show User info</a>
                        <a href="#/mesProtocolSettings" class="list-group-item" style="background-color:#222;border:none">Protocol Settings </a>
                    </div>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <label class="navbar-collapse-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#satyendra">
                  Satyendra<b class="caret"></b>
                </label>
                    <div class="collapse" id="satyendra">
                        <a href="#/createGroup" class="list-group-item" style="background-color:#222;border:none">Create Group </a>
                        <a href="#/showGroupList" class="list-group-item" style="background-color:#222;border:none">Show Group</a>
                        <a href="#/spindleSettings" class="list-group-item" style="background-color:#222;border:none">Spindle Settings</a>
                        <a href="#/openProtocol" class="list-group-item" style="background-color:#222;border:none">Open Protocol</a>

                    </div>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <label class="navbar-collapse-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#rpt">
                  RPT<b class="caret"></b>
                </label>
                    <div class="collapse" id="rpt">
                        <a href="#/restData" class="list-group-item" style="background-color:#222;border:none">Rest Data </a>
                        <a href="#/socketData" class="list-group-item" style="background-color:#222;border:none">Socket data</a>
                    </div>
            </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
</div> `
```

Comment: Look at this for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27443484/dropdown-closes-on-focus

Comment: Thanx.I found one and my task done.Here's a alike demo for that:
http://jsfiddle.net/gNUEx/